# ViewControllers and View instances

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

This is a memory question. I apologize if it's already been asked, but given the difficulty of describing the question succinctly, it makes it a difficult question to search for on StackOverflow.

Imagine this scenario:

- You have a single full screen view.
- You're going to lay out 10 cards from a deck of cards adjacent to
  each other on the view.
- Each card instance is a view which is controlled by a view
  controller.

Well when you're laying out these cards in a loop, are you really adding 10 view controller instances as child view controllers, with the 10 views as subviews, or is there in fact only 1 card view controller, and 10 card views, each card view managed by the same single view controller.

I know the answer if we were just talking plain ol' instances of NSObject... some class that has some properties and methods.  Creating 10 instances of a class creates 10 instance variables, but only 1 copy of the methods in memory.

Well, how does that concept translate to view controller instances and their views.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A `UIViewController` is nothing special, just another "class that has some properties and methods". One of those properties is the view controller's `view`. One view for one view controller.

So you would have 10 instances of your `UIViewController` subclass, each of which independently manages its `view`.

Comment: I wonder if the compiler is smart enough to keep only one copy of the methods in memory.  I'll have to fire up instruments and try it sometime with an actual project.  My scenario above was a hypothetical, so I don't have an app written where I could actually test the thought and see what instruments is saying.  I was hoping some mega Objective-c genius would happen upon this thread and just know the answer from their own wide ranging experience.